# PHP/MySQL Login Page Not Redirecting

Tags: php, mysql, redirect

I'm trying to create a login page that queries the database to check if the username and password are valid and allowing access to the following pages using sessions. Currently, I'm just using XAMPP to test the login. This is the following code I have in a PHP page.

```
<?php
  include("config.php");
  session_start();

  // Check for POST method
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $username = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $username);
    $password = stripslashes($_POST['password']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $password);

    //Search database for username and password
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users
    WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1"); // Prepared statement
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $user = $result->fetch_object();
    if(password_verify($_POST['password'], $user->password)) {
      echo("working");
      $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
      $_SESSION['user'] = $user->username;
      header("Location: index.php");
    } else {
      echo("no user");
    }
  }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="loginForm" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I added an echo statement just to see if it would output "no user" for both user/passwords sets in the database and not in it. They both display "no user" so I don't think I'm searching the database correctly. I'm sort of new to PHP and I used [this code](https://www.johnmorrisonline.com/build-php-login-form-using-sessions/).

### UPDATE

Thanks to comments, fixed passwords so that they were hashed.

When it still was not working:

**Set password datatype in database to VARCHAR(60), recommended VARCHAR(255)**

I realized it was because I had password datatype set to VARCHAR(40). Since I was using bycrypt to hash, it is a 60 character string. I set my password to the recommended VARCHAR(255) in case I decided to use PASSWORD_DEFAULT in the future. I failed to realize this is all mentioned in `password_hash()` [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) when initially creating the database and fields.

**Added `session_start()` to all pages referencing `$_SESSION[]`**

Echoed `var_dump()` to display the result of `password_verify()` that returned `true` when I entered the correct information, however, the page stil kept redirecting me to login. In the PHP I was redirecting to I had this section of code:

```
<?php
  if($_SESSION['loggedin'] == false) {
    header("Location: login.php");
  } else {
  }
?>
```

I forgot to put `session_start();` in the PHP page so it kept redirecting me to the login.

Comment: Note: You don't need to use `stripslashes()` or `mysqli_real_escape_string()` on values that you put into your query with `bind_param()` -- it handles that for you.

Comment: Thank you. I did not realise that. I will take that part out.

Comment: In order for this query to work, the value in the `users.password` field needs to have been created with `password_hash()`. Was it?

Comment: Oh that might be the problem then. Since I am running this on a local environment I just entered the data in mysql as plain text. Probably not the best way to save password onto the database...

Comment: You can generate the hash easily with: `php -r 'echo password_hash("whatever", PASSWORD_DEFAULT), "\n";'`

Comment: Got it. Thank you. For the information saved onto the mysql server i just did it through the command line. Is there a better way to be doing this if I want to hash a password and saved it on there?

Comment: Typically, you'd do that on the "register a new account" page.

Comment: Okay that was I was thinking. Thank you so much for your help!